# CGO undefined reference in included files

Tags: go, cgo

Wraping up OpenJtalk in Go, files are successfully included and types are referenced without an issue, but functions trigger an `undefined reference` error.

jtalk.go:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/home/vagrant/open_jtalk/njd [...etc]
/*
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// Main headers 
#include "mecab.h"
#include "njd.h"
#include "jpcommon.h"
#include "HTS_engine.h"

// Sub headers 
#include "text2mecab.h"
#include "mecab2njd.h"
#include "njd_set_pronunciation.h"
#include "njd_set_digit.h"
#include "njd_set_accent_phrase.h"
#include "njd_set_accent_type.h"
#include "njd_set_unvoiced_vowel.h"
#include "njd_set_long_vowel.h"
#include "njd2jpcommon.h"
*/
import "C"

type Open_JTalk struct {
   mecab C.Mecab           each of these struct references are fine
   njd C.NJD 
   jpcommon C.JPCommon 
   engine C.HTS_Engine 
}

func (open_jtalk *Open_JTalk) Open_JTalk_initialize() {
   C.Mecab_initialize(&open_jtalk.mecab)             // when any function is called the error happens
   C.NJD_initialize(&open_jtalk.njd)
   C.JPCommon_initialize(&open_jtalk.jpcommon)
   C.HTS_Engine_initialize(&open_jtalk.engine)
}

func main() {

}
```

And the weird part is that those same functions are declared right after the types:

mecab.h

```
// line 1584
typedef struct _Mecab{
   char **feature;
   int size;
   mecab_t *mecab;
} Mecab;

BOOL Mecab_initialize(Mecab *m);
```

Project webpage: http://open-jtalk.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add cgo linker options (`LDFLAGS`) with the path to and the name of your library. e.g.

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -Iyour-include-path
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Lyour-library-path -lyour-library-name-minus-the-lib-part
```

Comment: Alternaively (if available): `// #cgo pkg-config: onelib anotherlib`

Comment: This works for all minus `-L/home/vagrant/open_jtalk/mecab/src -llibmecab` :  **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmecab**.
And I have **libmecab** on that folder and in `/usr/local/lib/`, both static and dynamic.

Comment: How about -lmecab (remove the lib)?