# Creating static binaries from Go and C/C++ code (using cgo)

Tags: c++, docker, go, cgo, buffalo

I am developing an application in Go that needs to call some of my company's C++ code. Thus far, I have successfully achieved the following:

- Written C wrappers that enable instantiation of C++ objects
- Compiled my new C/C++ code into a shared library
- Linked the shared library when building my Go code
- Built the code within a Docker image

For example, the following currently works:

```sh
$ export CGO_LDFLAGS="-L${PWD}/resources/lib (...) -lcompany -lxerces-c++ (...) -lstdc++ -no-pie"
$ export CGO_CFLAGS="-I${PWD}/resources/inc"
$ export CGO_CXXFLAGS="-I${PWD}/resources/inc
$ go build . -o /bin/app
```

**I would like to reduce the size of the final Docker image.** I'm using the [Buffalo web framework](https://gobuffalo.io), and accordingly, I'm building my app with their Docker image. The final size of the image (after I've included my team's libraries, etc.) is over 3 GB.

The Buffalo team recommends building the application into a static binary, like so:

```sh
$ buffalo build --static -o /bin/app                                       # buffalo
$ go build -o /bin/app -ldflags -linkmode external -extldflags "-static"   # go
```

Running these, however, gives me a plethora of "undefined reference" errors. For example, the `xerces-c++`library I'm linking in the above example gives the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:141: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:142: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:147: undefined reference to `curl_multi_add_handle'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:159: undefined reference to `curl_easy_getinfo'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:124: undefined reference to `curl_slist_append'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:102: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:99: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:89: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/vicar/external/xerces-c++/v3.0.0_rhel6/src/src/xercesc/util/NetAccessors/Curl/CurlURLInputStream.cpp:90: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
```

I was able to get this error to go away by installing `libcurl4` via `apt-get install libcurl4` and linking it with `-lcurl`, but then *it* complains about undefined references. It goes on and on.

Given this context, my questions are as follows:

- Is listing all libraries like this a necessary evil to achieve what I want? Is there no better alternative?
- Can I achieve my end goal of smaller Docker image size another way?

Thanks for taking the time. Let me know if I can provide more information to make solving this problem easier.

**Update:** I've been able to get my final Docker image to a reasonable size (~600MB) by using a multi-stage build. However, I would still like to know the answer to my original questions, so I'm leaving this question unanswered for now.

Comment: First you need to find biggest file of yours then find out what makes it so big. Q: Are you building your C++ files stripped or with debug information? (my guess: "with debug info", just call the Linux `file binaryfile`  command and you'll see it says not stripped! also see for Go: `export GOFLAGS="-ldflags=-s" `

Comment: The final binary isn't large (about 30MB); however, the Docker image itself is. That's because I'm using the buffalo base image, which is by itself 1.8 GB. I'm trying to create a static binary that I can just drop into an alpine container. Just checked, no, I haven't been stripping the files. I tried running with the `GOFLAGS` option you suggested, which worked (verified with `file`), but the size difference was negligible.

Comment: So run `docker history alpine:3.10.3` (replace your image name and tag) to see what size the layers have in docker image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29438761/13860

Comment: @Flimzy so the answer to my question is yes, I have to explicitly list all of the libraries, and all of their dependencies? No clean way to do it? And whenever a dependency changes, I have to list that change as well?

Comment: It seems you're using the default buffalo Docker image as a base. While it's a good base to compile your binary, you should use a multi-stage Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks @StanislasMichalak, I was able to bring the final image size down quite a bit by doing that. Definitely helps.